# Meaning of the word "Altleichen"

Tags: meaning, noun

What does the word „Altleichen“ mean? It was used as „Es ist schon Altleichen“. Is it used in positive or negative way (considering the word Leichen)?

Comment: More context would be helpful. Since I never encountered that word: is mishearing possible?

Comment: It _could_ mean something like “ancient history, all bodies have been buried, let's move on”, but we’d need more context to make sure.

Comment: This seems to be relatively recent slang since DWDS neither defines it or has any examples in it's usage database. But I found *Ich bin gespannt welche Altleichen der vorletzte Landesfuerst so hinterlassen hat.* on Twitter and a few other examples on Google. The literal translation of *Altleiche* is "old-corpse", but what sort of figurative meaning is intended I can only guess.

Comment: @RDBury It's apparently a creative mix of "Leichen im Keller" and "Altlasten". (I haven't encountered this word before but the meaning in that context is pretty clear.)

Comment: The sentence „Es ist schon Altleichen.“ doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @Roland: That would be my guess too, corresponding, more or less, to "skeletons in the closet". An almost homonym of *Leiche* is *Leich*, a form of medieval poetry/song. Probably not relevant here since only the plural dative ends with *-en*. But I suppose that, allowing for faulty spelling/grammar, and the fact that no context is given, it can't be ruled out completely.

Comment: I've only come across one example, which referes to obsolete components in a home automation system, ie ones that are no longer operating. But that was "ob es Altleichen sind".

Comment: I actually have come across that word, although it's certainly not very common. In some Austrian provinces, public health officers are paid a higher fee for work performed on “Brandleichen, **Altleichen**, Wasserleichen, Verwesungsleichen” as opposed to “regular” fresh corpses.

Comment: There was a case in the UK where a man was suspected of murdering his wife, police dug up his garden, found a skull, and he promptly admitted everything. Then the skull came back from forensics and was found to be 1200 years old. It seems it was part of an "Altleiche".

Comment: I know "Altleichen" since childhood (45+ years ago) as a colloquial figurative expression for things that have been obsolete for a very long time (and like @Ingmar, literally as bodies in criminal investigations that are not victims of recent crimes), but I do not know an authoritative source.  In any case, it would have to be "sind Altleichen", not the singular "ist".

Comment: I can imagine "Altleichen" as obsoletes parts of something (that have been obsolete for a long time) as well. But in the sentence "Es ist schon Altleichen", doesn't it feel like the word denotes a point in time? Maybe it's an alternative/regional or outdated term for a (christian?) holiday like Fronleichnam, or maybe a (less than successful) attempt at a joke (like calling Fronleichnam "Happy Kadaver").

Comment: @Eike Pierstorff: I'm thinking it's similar to the English programmer slang term "cruft", meaning useless, redundent code. I'm familiar with it from Wikipedia where it's used to describe useless trivia that no one has bothered to delete. (Believe it or not, in my experience it easier to add material to Wikipedia than to get rid of it.) If *Altleiche* is a few decades old then I think it must be either regional or jargon, otherwise I don't know why there wouldn't be any hits in the DWDS usage database.

Comment: @RDBury, I grew up in Baden Württemberg in the general area of Stuttgart, if that is any help with finding a regionalism. Since the meaning is similar to the rather common "Altlasten" (except that an "Altlast" might still be in use instead of just being around and surfacing at embarrassing moments) I guess it just isn't used very often.

Comment: @Eike Pierstorff - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swabian_German) says the Baden Württemberg motto is *Wir können alles. Außer Hochdeutsch.* :) I guess that would explain the different vocabulary. I get the impression that *Altlasten* are not only obsolete and inconvenient, but hazardous as well.

Comment: @RDBury, I am in IT, and here "Altlast" would usually refer to some technical debt. But that is again figuratively, and yes, in a literal sense that would be usually toxic or otherwise hazardous. It's just that I much more often use the word figuratively than in its literal meaning, so that was the first to come to mind.

Comment: Is it a written sentence or have you heard it somewhere? Please supply more context. Im the present form nobody will be able to give a reasonable answer. I vote to close your question.

Comment: @Roland: Possibly, "Karteileichen" also play into the mix.

Answer (score 3):

The German noun *"Leiche"* means: dead body, corpse, cadaver.
The adjective *"alt"* means: old.

In German, there is this excessively used feature of compound words, so you can join them together to one word: *Altleiche = old corpse.* But this specific compound noun is rarely used. It refers to a corpse that has been lying around somewhere for a long time without being properly buried, most often in a figurative sense.

So if you have some files on your computer that should have been deleted years ago because they are no longer needed, you could call them *"Altleichen".* Or if a politician had an illicit affair 20 or 30 years ago, which has not yet been made public, but which certain people know about, then one can also call such long-ago affairs and scandals *"Altleichen".* But as said before: It is rare that this word is used.

---

The sentence *"Es ist schon Altleichen"* doesn't make any sense. It makes as much sense as the English sentence *"It is already old corpses".*

Comment: @Ingmar: Was genau hat dich veranlasst diesen Kommentar zu schreiben? Hat irgend jemand eine politische Diskussion anzettelt?

Comment: @Ingmar: Für mich sah es so aus (und tut es noch), als würde sich dein Kommentar auf meine Antwort beziehen. Wenn das gar nicht der Fall ist, würde ich dich bitten deine beiden Kommentare zu löschen, dann lösche ich auch meine. Denn ganz offensichtlich gibt es die Ursache der Kommentare nicht mehr.